# I included necessary header file but get "error: gai_strerrorA was not declared in this scope", ubuntu16.04, g++ 5.5

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, compiler-errors, g++

I'm moving a code which runs on widows to linux now. Much part is using standard libraries but there are still some compile errors that I have to remove.  Now, the error comes from this line

```
printf("[err] getaddrinfo: %s[%d] (%s, %d)\n", gai_strerrorA(ret), ret, server_addr, port);
```

and the error message is below.

> g++ -Iinclude/ -Isource/ -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas
> -Wfatal-errors -fPIC  -std=c++11 -lm -lpthread -lrt -mavx -c source/sSocket2.cpp -o obj/sSocket2.o source/sSocket2.cpp: In member
> function bool sj::cSocket2::ConnectUDP(const char*, int, int,
> int, int):
>
> source/sSocket2.cpp:125:68: error: gai_strerrorA was not declared in
> this scope
> printf("[err] getaddrinfo: %s[%d] (%s, %d)\n", gai_strerrorA(ret), ret, server_addr, port);

When I look up gai_strerrorA (https://linux.die.net/man/3/gai_strerror), it requires to #include <sys/types.h>, <sys/socket.h> and <netdb.h> so I added all those 3 files in the #include. But the error is still coming. What should I do?  should I install some library files?
(this is on ubuntu 16.04, g++ (Ubuntu 5.5.0-12ubuntu1~16.04) 5.5.0 20171010)

Comment: The manual page you link to mentions `gai_strerror` but not `gai_strerrorA`. There exists a [`gai_strerrorA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ws2tcpip/nf-ws2tcpip-gai_strerrora) function in **Windows**, which is a Windows-specific extension to the standard `gai_strerror` function.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Ah, that was it. How silly I am.. :) Thank you!

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I changed gai_strerrorA to gai_strerror, now it's gone. (if you make your comment an answer, I'll choose it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`gai_strerrorA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ws2tcpip/nf-ws2tcpip-gai_strerrora) function is a Windows-specific extension for "ASCII" strings (as opposed the [`gai_strerrorW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ws2tcpip/nf-ws2tcpip-gai_strerrorw) for "Unicode" characters).

The plain POSIX standard function is just [`gai_strerror`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/gai_strerror.html), without any character-specific suffix (Windows uses macros to define the suffix-less `gai_strerror` "function" depending on other macros).